# ReactJS MUI 5 how to add transition to an opening/closing drawer

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, navigation-drawer

Uisng [this](https://mui.com/components/drawers/#clipped-under-the-app-bar) as a reference I've created a collapsible drawer that shrinks the content area next to it. Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-pare-eu69v1?file=/src/Layout.js). My question is how to add a smooth transition as in [this example](https://mui.com/components/drawers/#persistent-drawer) but not using `styled`. I tried with something like in the codesandbox, but it does weird things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is Drawer variant `persistent`.

Change line #53 from this

```
variant={openDrawer ? "permanent" : "temporary"}
```

to this:

```
variant="persistent"
```

That's the only line I changed and it works really well now.